# SQL Server stops when I right click on any table instance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

When I right-click the instance of a table on the SQL Server 2005, it stops with the message:

> Microsoft sql server is busy waiting for the internal operation to complete.

If I try to open a new instance of SQL Server Managemente Studio it can't open and shows me the message:

> Could not load file or assembly 'EnvDTE, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=...' or one of its dependencies.  The system cannot find the file specified.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem using the hint from the event Viewer, (something I didn't noticed before).

There were two error notifications:

1. > Product: Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Team Explorer - ENU -- Error 1706. An installation package for the product Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Team Explorer - ENU cannot be found. Try the installation again using a valid copy of the installation package 'vs_setup.msi'.
2. > Product: Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Team Explorer - ENU -- Error 1712. One or more of the files required to restore your computer to its previous state could not be found.  Restoration will not be possible.

I just executed the `vs_setup.msi` from **the Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Team Explorer** and it worked again normally.
It was fixed and working normally, hope this message will help anybody with the same problem.